# how to calculate percisely the character movement in a tiles

Tags: javascript

So, i have started building a game 2d just a few day so its make me so confuse with some reason of the movement character in the tilemap.In my tilemap, every per tiles[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCmbG.png) is have the width and height 16px and the whole map is 800 x 1250, every movement of my character will add/sub 1 in per step, when I calculating detection collisions, the position became wrong position specifically when character move a step then the position return to far though i try to divide 16 px in every movement of character.
This is my movement:

```
this.setting_walking_speed = 3 ;
if (this.player.control_direction[0] == 1) {
this.player.x -= this.setting_walking_speed;
this.player.walking = 1;
this.player.direction = 0;

            } else if (this.player.control_direction[1] == 1) {
    
                this.player.y -= this.setting_walking_speed;
                this.player.walking = 1;
                this.player.direction = 2;
    
            } else if (this.player.control_direction[2] == 1) {
                this.player.x += this.setting_walking_speed;
                this.player.walking = 1;
                this.player.direction = 1;
            } else if (this.player.control_direction[3] == 1) {
                this.player.y += this.setting_walking_speed;
                this.player.walking = 1;
                this.player.direction = 3;
            }
            var posf = {
                x:Math.floor( this.player.y /16 ) ,  
                y:Math.floor( this.player.x /16 )  
            };
            this.collide(posf);
            console.log(posf.x  , posf.y);

}
```

And the collision function is:

```
The this.setting_minblocksize\[k\] = 16;
this.bound = this.draw_collision();

        function rectangularCollision({rect1, rect2 }) {
            return ( 
                rect1.x  >= rect2.x  &&
                rect1.x <= rect2.x   &&
                rect1.y  <= rect2.y  &&  
                rect1.y  >= rect2.y 
            )
        }
    
        this.collide = function(player){
            // console.log(this.bound);
            this.bound.forEach((boundaries) => {
                if(
                    rectangularCollision({,
                        rect1: player,
                        rect2: boundaries
                    })
                ){
                    console.log('collide');
                }
            })
        }
    
        this.draw_collision = function () {
            var obj = [];
            this.ctxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            for (var i = 0; i < canvas.height; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < canvas.width; j++) {
    
                    var data = 0;
                    if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < this.map.layers[1].height && j < this.map.layers[1].width) {
                        var data = this.map.layers[1].data[i * this.map.layers[1].width + j];
                        for (var k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                            this.ctxt.fillStyle = 'red';
                            if (data != 0) {
                                obj.push({
                                    x: j ,    
                                    y: i
                                });
                                this.ctxt.fillRect(
                                    (j * this.setting_minblocksize[k]) ,
                                    (i * this.setting_minblocksize[k]) ,
                                    this.setting_minblocksize[k],
                                    this.setting_minblocksize[k]
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

[image]

[My codepen link is right here](https://codepen.io/chew-chew23/pen/MWXdEgX?editors=1011)
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: The question should be updated to include  code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: you mean a whole project?

Comment: If you have a link to a CodePen (or similar) that would work.  You don't need to post the entire project here, but the code that has been posted is clearly incomplete.  Questions that include enough code to easily reproduce the problem tend to receive more and better answers.

Comment: ok i ve already add it

Comment: Even after cleaning and ignoring js1, your JS code is still 465 lines. Is there  any way you could do a minimal reproducible example? Also, the language in your questions a little hard to figure out, maybe you could try and make what you are asking a little clearer as well? The codepen looks like it works OK for me; I don't really know what to solve here

Comment: Start by fixing the posf calculation which incorrectly mixes X and Y values.  The second problem is there is an offset between player and tile grid.  You need to add +1 to the X and Y values of posf.